# Rounding an Objective-C float to the nearest .05

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, rounding

I want to round the following floating point numbers to the nearest 0.05.

449.263824 --> 449.25

390.928070 --> 390.90

390.878082 --> 390.85

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: what is the rounding pattern? looks like some sort of round to the nearest .05? except not really, since the 2nd and 3rd examples don't conform. We need more info.

Comment: Here is the correct pattern i want to achive

449.263824 --> 449.25

390.928070 --> 390.90

390.878082 --> 390.85

Comment: That is the same pattern in the question.  Do want the second answer to be 390.90 or 390.95 for 390.928070?

Comment: For people who don't see the pattern, the questioner wants to round the number to the nearest 0.05.

Comment: except that last one the OP just posted isn't to the nearest .05.

Comment: Just for clarification, 2 decimal places is the following: 390.928070 = **390.93** and 390.878082 = **390.89**

Comment: He wants to round down, not to the nearest 0.05 he should update his question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The match the output in your question, you can do the following:

```
float customRounding(float value) {
    const float roundingValue = 0.05;
    int mulitpler = floor(value / roundingValue);
    return mulitpler * roundingValue;
}
```

Example:

```
NSLog(@"Output: %f --> %.2f", 449.263824, customRounding(449.263824));
```

Comment: This was helpful but I'm curious why this uses floor() and not round(). Wouldn't the former chop off all the remainder, instead of bringing it closer to the nearest number you are looking for?

Comment: The title of the question doesn't really match what the OP asked in the question.  In the comments of the question, the OP wanted the answers to round `down` always.  The [round function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round) returns `nearest integer, rounding away from zero in halfway cases`. I could have played with the [rounding mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/FE_round). But to keep things simply, I used [floor function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor). So it all depends on what your requirements are. [Sample Code](http://ideone.com/YYVD2P)

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the OP either needs to update the question, or change his examples to match it.

Comment: 0.04 will be rounded down to 0.00 instead of 0.05 . Replace "floor" by "roundf" and it will works perfectly

Comment: @YauheniShauchenka [using roundf is the same thing as using round](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round); they both produce the same behavior.  Using the [roundf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round) on value 2.99 would result in 3.00.  The OP wants the result to be 2.95.

Comment: @BlackFrog so what do you want to say by your comment about roundf and round? I just noted that you should replace "floor" by "roundf" or if you wish by "round".. that's it.

Answer (score 4):

There's the [round()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/roundf.3.html) function.  I think you need to do this:

```
double rounded = round(number * 20.0) / 20.0;
```

As with all floating point operations, since 1/5 is not directly representable as a binary value, you'll see bizarre not quite exact results.  If you don't like that, you can use NSDecimalNumber's [-decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehaviour:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000179-decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior_) method but it'll be a bit slower.

Comment: @Yasir, how can you mark this as the correct answer when `round(390.928070 * 20.0) / 20.0 = 390.95`?  In your question you want the output to be **390.90**

Comment: @Yasir: Black Frog makes a good point; and I'm still unclear whether you want round down to the first multiple of 0.05 below the current value or whether you want to truncate to 2dp and round to the nearest 0.05 from there.

Comment: @Black Frog: Clearly he made a mistake in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is answered but I used the following code:

```
float unrounded = 2.234;

float decimal = 0.05;
float decimal2 = 1/decimal;
float rounded = (((int)((unrounded*decimal2)+0.5))/decimal2);
```

For example:

```
> unrounded = 2.234 
> decimal = 0.05
> decimal2 = 1/0.05 = 20
> 
> rounded:
> 2.234 * 20 = 44.68
> 44.68 + 0.5 = 45.18 
> make an integer: 45 
> 45 / 20 = 2.25
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to carry out rounding and indeed to specify the rounding you require via one of the `NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode` options. (Search for "NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode" in the above class reference to see the defaults.)

However, as @Jesse states in the comment on your question, there doesn't seems to be any standard form of rounding going on in the examples you're provided.

Answer (score 0):

If it were round to the nearest x, then you could go with:

```
roundedValue = originalValue + x * 0.5;
roundedValue -= fmodf(roundedValue, x);
```

As it is, it isn't entirely clear what you want.

Comment: Here is the correct pattern i want to achive

449.263824 --> 449.25

390.928070 --> 390.90

390.878082 --> 390.85

Answer (score 0):

Use `floor`:

```
#include <math.h>
...
double result = floor(number * 20.0) / 20.0;
```