# How to round a number up to nearest x incremental value

Tags: objective-c, math, rounding

Im having issues with a block of code that involves rounding floats to the nearest upper x. What i'm trying to do is take whatever number i have and round it up to the next highest x. My code seems to work 80% of the time, but have recently found some cases where it is not returning a number that i would expect. For example, if i wanted it rounded to the next highest 500, the code below shows what i would have.

`CGFloat number = 3780;
roundedNumber = 500 *ceilf(number/500 +.5);`

Here i would expect the answer to return 4000. Instead, it returns 4,500.

Is there something about the math above that i am missing/not understanding? why is it only for some case this seems to "over round" my numbers? is there a simpler way to get what i'm after than this?

Comment: I know this duplicate talks about fraction [Objective-c Rounding float to the nearest .05](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678562/objective-c-rounding-float-to-the-nearest-05), but you could modified it to handle 100.

Comment: Because you're both using `ceilf` and doing "manual" rounding with the `.5`, so you round up twice.

Comment: `500 * round(number / 500)`

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
3780 /500 + 0.5 -> 7.56 + 0.5 -> 8.06
ceil(8.06) -> 9
9 * 500 -> 4500
```